# swift while using two different tableviews for the same cell id, indexPath.row becomes out fo range

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

As I'm using same ViewCell for two different tableViews in the same viewController, once I click inside one different cell in one table and return to the other table to get inside other cell, indexPath.row is increasing, as a result the app crashes and gives "index out of range" for the  cell?.TextLable.text = QRinstructionList[indexPath.row]

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.black
    if (tableView == tableViewQR){
         cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "instructionCellId") as! InstructionsTableViewCell
         cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none

        print("tableViewQR: count: \(QRiconList.count)")
        print("tableViewQR: row: \(indexPath.row)")
        print("tableViewQR: \(QRiconList[indexPath.row])")

        cell?.iconInstructionImage.image = UIImage(named: QRiconList[indexPath.row])
         cell?.TextLable.text = QRinstructionList[indexPath.row]


        return cell!
    }else{
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "instructionCellId") as! InstructionsTableViewCell

        cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
        cell!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

        cell?.TextLable.text = instructionList[indexPath.row]
        cell?.iconInstructionImage.image = UIImage(named: iconList[indexPath.row])
        //   print(cell?.IconNameVariable)
        if(cell?.TextLable.text == "MultipleCardInfo.Instructions".localized()){
        }

        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if(tableView == tableViewQR){
            return QRinstructionList.count
        }else{
             return instructionList.count
        }
    }

Comment: each Array has 3 elements as a total number (instructionList, QRinstructionList)

Comment: instructionList = []
        QRinstructionList = []
        instructionList.append("MultipleCardInfo.Transactions".localized())
        instructionList.append("MultipleCardInfo.AddMoney".localized())
        instructionList.append("MultipleCardInfo.Instructions".localized())
        QRinstructionList.append("MultipleCardInfo.Instructions".localized())
        QRinstructionList.append("MultipleCardInfo.MakePayment".localized())
        QRinstructionList.append("MultipleCardInfo.AddMoney".localized())
        instructionTableView.reloadData()

Comment: start var names with small letter this `QRinstructionList` to `qRinstructionList`

Answer (score 0):

You need to return correct count for each table inside `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return tableView ==  tableViewQR ?  qRinstructionList.count :  instructionList.count
}
```